# Flex slider moves without the images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

I have been try every thing to discover why the images is not appears inside the flex slider of the phonegap app in my IPhone, i have been check the orders of the link and every thing but no images appears.

-when i try to change **https** of js&css links of flexslider to **http** , this is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nrZG.jpg)

-when i put links of js&css of flexslider to **https**  this is the result and the slider moves without images (https: //i.stack.imgur.com/H0c2i.jpg)

- when i remove both links images appears as a list -_-

i have try it on a fiddle and its work but not work on my mobile http://jsfiddle.net/CPpBD/677/
its the same links and every thing

//html

```
 <html>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://*.gstatic.com * ws:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://*.googleapis.com https://*.cloudflare.com data: blob:;media-src *;img-src 'self' http://192.168.1.157 https://*.gstatic.com https://*.googleapis.com data: content:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
                <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/flexslider.min.css" />  
            <body>
                <div id="markerListPage" data-role="page"> </div>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
            <script src="js/markerdetails.js"></script>

            </body> 
        </html>
```

//Marker details html

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <body>
            <div id="detailsPage" data-role="page">

                        <div data-role="content" id="pic">
                            <div class="flexslider" >
                                <ul class="slides">

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                      </div>    
           </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

//javascript of detailsmarker page

```
$('#detailsPage').live('pageshow', function (event) {
    var id = getUrlVars()["L_ID"];
    var serviceURL = "http://192.168.1.157/maleem/";
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getimage.php?L_ID=' + id, displayImg);  
});

function displayImg(data) {

    var imgs = data.pics;
    console.log(imgs);

    for(var j=0;j<imgs.length;j++)
    {
        $('.slides').append('<li><img  src="' + imgs[j].img + '" width="200" height="200"/></li>'); 
    }

    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: true
    });
}
```

Comment: When building PhoneGap/Cordova apps, your CSS and JavaScript files should be packaged into the app, not referenced from online sources. Also have a look at the Whitelist plugin to allow external sources: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html

Comment: even when i store the file in javascript and css folder of my www folder,ex: <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></sccript> images not appears :(

Comment: Where are the images coming from? They should either be local too, or their source domain should be whitelisted.

Comment: they are local in a local server

Comment: By "local" I meant packaged within the app. Even if the server is in your local network, that's considered as an external source by PhoneGap and should be whitelisted. Also make sure that the device you're testing on is on the same LAN if you're using a local IP address.

Comment: yes i know , all images when i remove https or http from the flexslder links like this <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.6.3.... ></script> its appears, my problem why the images not combined with flex slider

Comment: @DarthJDG if am using RTL jquery css&js , is this will affect the slider?